# Short-urls without index files?

Tags: apache, url

I'm wondering how urls like these are generated: `http://www.example.com/Xj7hF`

This is a practice I have seen used by many url shorteners as well as other websites that supposedly don't want to display data in the url in a parameter format.

Surely they can't be placing index files in the folder destination `/Xj7hF` etc with a redirect to the actual url, so I'm wondering how this is done.

Any help would be very appreciated!

(I'm running on a Linux server with Apache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different web development frameworks and web servers do it in different ways, but, the most common is probably using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with apache. Basically, the web server sends the request to a dynamic scripting language (eg. PHP) rewritten in such a way that the script doesn't need to know what the original request URI looked like and the client browser doesn't need to know what script actually processed the request.

For example, You will often see:

http://something.com/123/

This is a request for `/123` which Apache may rewrite as a request to `/my_script.php?id=123` based on how the user configured mod_rewrite.

(.htaccess example)

```
# if the request is for a file or directory that
# does not actually exist, serve index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was just looking through `mod_rewrite` here - http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php, but didn't really understand how to create a new rewrite rule for say `http://www.example.com/xH7hJ` to `http://www.example.com/goto/?url=xH7hJ`. Any ideas how that can be done? I've seen this particular example which gets everything after grab and appends it to the rewritten url `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^grab /public/files/download/download.php`, but I don't have a prefix aside from `/`?

Comment: You might have something along these lines:

Comment: So that rewrite rule (didn't test, just off the top of my head) would redirect /xH7hJ to index.php?url=xH7hJ. Then the index.php script could do whatever it needs to do. The two Rewrite Conditions make sure that rewriting is only done when the requested file or directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out on a spare domain and report back! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting) and is usually performed via proper configuration of the webserver.  StackOverflow has [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting?sort=votes) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) for this, so you should be able to find more information there.